# When creating a cone, why do we start with three points?

Tags: category-theory

[Follow up to this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2995067/what-exactly-is-called-cone-in-the-category-theory-and-how-does-it-relate-to-a/2995099#comment9652342_2995099).

> The simplest way to think of a cone is to take any diagram, for instance:
> $$
> \bullet \to \bullet \gets \bullet
> $$
> where the bullets are objects in some category and the arrows are morphisms. Then you add a point "above" the diagram (the *apex*), with arrows pointing to each of the bullets.
> $$
> \begin{align*}
>  & &  \color{red}\bullet & &   \\
>  & ~~\swarrow & \downarrow & ~~~~~~\searrow & \\
> \bullet & ~~~\to & \bullet & ~~~\gets & \bullet
> \end{align*}
> $$
> This is a cone when every triangle coming from this construction commutes.
>
> ...

Why does the construction start with three dots? In the formal definition, I understand that the cone is the natural transformations of an object viewed as a functor to another functor. So don't we just need two objects to complete the commutative square?

Comment: It isn’t that the construction requires starting with 3 dots. The author is trying to explain why it’s called a “cone”, and this is a visual illustration.

Comment: Let me rephrase, why do almsot every visual illustration of cones start with three dots? @MarkSaving

Comment: "almost every visual illustration of cones start with three dots" this is simply not true, so I guess you fell in some biased sample

Comment: read [this](https://bartoszmilewski.com/2014/05/08/understanding-limits-2/)

Comment: you spittin straight hard facts @DanielTeixeira. I'd delete this question since the thought is proven wrong but I have seen four - five book which do this so I am keeping it. Thanx again :D